# Kubernetes deployment via Web UI - 'Failed to pull image' error

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am creating a deployment using "CREATE AN APP" option from the Kubernetes UI page on windows - with two pods and external service. The image being used is available. However, I am getting an error saying:

```
**Search Line limits were exceeded, some search paths have been omitted, the 
applied search line is: my-namespace.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local <ORG DOMAIN NAMES>**

**Failed to pull image "dockerUserName/python-app-image": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: manifest for dockerUserName/python-app-image:latest not found**
```

I am new to K8S and have no idea like where I am going wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you want to report a bug, do that using the bugtracker of whatever software you're using. Be prepared to describe your setup a bit further so people stand a chance reproducing it. If you wanted to ask a programming question here, you'd have to extract and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is thrown by the Docker daemon when the image cannot be found. Verify that the image and tag you are trying actually exist by running `docker pull dockerUserName/python-app-image:latest`.

Alternatively, run `docker images` to get a list of images you have already pulled and check the TAG column.

Keep in mind that the `latest` tag for Docker is just a naming convention. You need to create it and keep it updated yourself, it does not automatically give you the last pushed image.